# Error from python panda timedelta function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this line of code:

```
df['datetime']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])+ pd.to_timedelta(df['hour']/100,unit='hour')
```

and I am getting this error:

```
invalid timedelta unit hour provided
```

the strange things are that it works on another PC but not in this PC.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have on that machine?

Comment: @Deepstop how can I check?

Comment: `python -m pip list` from the command line perhaps. Or import pandas and then `pandas.__version__`

Comment: So did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I'll take a stab at it. Pandas appears to have introduced `unit=hour` and `unit=hours` in either V0.24 or 0.25. If running an earlier version, then use

```
df['datetime']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])+ pd.to_timedelta(df['hour']/100,unit='h')
```

instead. The [docs from 0.23.4](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) don't show `hour` and `hours` as options, while the [docs for 0.25](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) clearly do. That would explain the different behaviour on different machines.